# special characters to html entity using php

Tags: php, entity

I want to convert special characters like ñ, Ñ to htmlentities using php.

I tried using htmlentities, but instead of returning "&ntilde" for its value it returns "Ã±" as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your page charset is set to `utf-8`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the character set you use as the third parameter to [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities). The default character set is `iso-8859-1`. If you use UTF-8 for your data, you need to say so:

```
$result = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the charset because the default is ASCII (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
htmlentities($stringToConvert, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: sorry typo: not ASCI but ISO-8859-1